# Distributed load on a slope/axle

Tags: statics, dynamics

In statics they teach you about distributed beams, how to calculate the total force, the engagement point, etc. I can't find any information anywhere on distributed loads on unevenly sloped surfaces / rods though. This is my situation. (Sorry, low quality rip from the Internet):

[image]

If I were to have the locations / angles of where the (unevenly) distributed load is (start location/angle and end location/angle), the radius of the rod etc. how can I calculate the distributed load as one vector? So the total length (force) of the vector, angle and engagement point of the force (as coordinates f.e.).

If anyone wants to know, I need to put these equations in a system of equations to calculate the normal force of a polishing belt on a crank journal. Even though my assumption of what normal force (distributed load) the polishing belt has on the crank journal is probably incorrect I will just assume my assumption is correct to continue my project

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me if you want to calculate and from which parameters are you starting. For example if you knew $T_1$ and $T_2$ from the torque you want to transfer and static tension in the belt, the resulting net sum of normal forces (one vector) should simply be $\overrightarrow{T}_1+\overrightarrow{T}_2$. So do you really need to calculate just one vector and do you already know the force $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the resultant force due to a variable distrubuted load on a generic profile, you can follow this line of reasoning (if you're not interested in the reasoning, scroll to the end of each section for the results).

Begin by describing the load and surface where the load acts on:

[image]

Here we use polar coordinates to describe the surface $r(\theta)$ and the generic load $p(\theta)$, that can be considered acting on a length $ds$ of the profile.
Remember that: $$ds=\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+\left(\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta$$

You are interested in calculating the resultant components $F_x$ and $F_y$ of the distributed load. You may be interested in the torque $T$ imparted by the load as well.

To calculate these you have to decompose the load like this:

[image]

The generic distributed load is inclined by an angle $\phi$ wrt the $\hat{r}$ direction, and this is what could produce the torque.

**Finding $F_x$**

Let's start by finding $F_x$. I will use the picture above as the basis for the signs, and use the standard convention of right, up and counterclockwise as positive.

$F_x$ is given by two contributions: one is due to $p_r(\theta)$ and the other is due to $p_\theta(\theta)$: $$p_r(\theta)=p(\theta)\cdot\cos(\phi(\theta))\\p_\theta(\theta)=p(\theta)\cdot\sin(\phi(\theta))$$

Now we can sum the contributions: $$F_x=\int_{s_1}^{s_2}p_\theta(\theta)\cdot\sin(\theta)\,ds-\int_{s_1}^{s_2}p_r(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta)\,ds$$
and substituting $p_r(\theta)$, $p_\theta(\theta)$ and $ds$ with the results found before, we get the following: $$F_x=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\color{red}{p(\theta)\cdot\sin(\phi(\theta))}\cdot\sin(\theta)\cdot\color{red}{\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+\left(\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)^2}\,d\theta}
-\\\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\color{red}{p(\theta)\cdot\cos(\phi(\theta))}\cdot\cos(\theta)\cdot\color{red}{\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+\left(\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)^2}\,d\theta}\\
=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\left[\sin(\phi(\theta))\cdot\sin(\theta)-\cos(\phi(\theta))\cdot\cos(\theta)\right]\cdot\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+\left(\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)^2}\,d\theta$$

This is quite a big integral, but luckily it's a general formula and can be simplified in some cases.
Let's suppose the profile is a circle: $$r(\theta)=const\\\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}=0$$
Now it all simplifies to this: $$F_x=r\cdot\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\left[\sin(\phi(\theta))\cdot\sin(\theta)-\cos(\phi(\theta))\cdot\cos(\theta)\right]\,d\theta$$
You could also suppose that the relative inclination of the distributed load, $\phi(\theta)$ is constant as well along the profile: $$F_x=r\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\left[\sin(\phi)\cdot\sin(\theta)-\cos(\phi)\cdot\cos(\theta)\right]\,d\theta
\\=r\cdot\sin(\phi)\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\sin(\theta)\,d\theta-r\cdot\cos(\phi)\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$$
A very specific case is one where $\phi=0$, but remember that in practice it's hard to get this configuration because you cannot transmit torque if no component of the load points in the $\hat{\theta}$ direction. Anyway here's the formula:$$F_x=-r\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$$

To keep going now, you have to describe the distributed load, $p(\theta)$, which could be linear, similar to your picture: $$p(\theta)-T_1=\frac{T_2-T_1}{\theta_2-\theta_1}\cdot(\theta-\theta_1)$$

And you can isolate $p(\theta)$ and then substitute that inside the integral and get the net force. The integration is easy at this point, just tedious.

**What about $F_y$?**

You can find $F_y$ in the same way, you just have to construct the integrals with the y components of the distributed load: $$F_y=-\int_{s_1}^{s_2}p_\theta(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta)\,ds-\int_{s_1}^{s_2}p_r(\theta)\cdot\sin(\theta)\,ds$$
After applying the same substitutions as before and simplifying, you end up with: $$F_y=-\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot[\sin(\phi(\theta))\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi(\theta))]\cdot\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+\left(\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)^2}\,d\theta$$
And again, in case of circular profile as above, the formula simplifies to: $$F_y=-r\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot[\sin(\phi(\theta))\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi(\theta))]\,d\theta$$
For constant $\phi$ we get:$$F_y=-r\cdot\sin(\phi)\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\cos(\theta)\,d\theta-r\cdot\cos(\phi)\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)\cdot\sin(\theta)\,d\theta$$

**How do we find the torque?**

To find the torque we can follow a similar path. Remember that the only component that generates torque is $p_\theta(\theta)$, as $p_r(\theta)$ points radially in and doesn't produce any torque: $$T=-\int_{s_1}^{s_2}p_\theta(\theta)\cdot r(\theta)\,ds$$
The minus sign is due to $p_\theta(\theta)$ pointing clockwise and me defining positive torque counterclockwise, but it's just a matter of convention and should not deserve too much attention.
Again let's substitute $p_\theta(\theta)$ and $ds$ with the formulas used before:$$T=-\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\color{red}{p(\theta)\cdot\sin(\phi(\theta))}\cdot r(\theta)\cdot\color{red}{\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+\left(\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta}$$
We can again assume circular profile and constant relative inclination:$$T=-r^2\sin(\phi)\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}p(\theta)d\theta$$
At this point you need to describe the load inside the integral to continue with the calculations.

**Once the two forces and the torque are found, where do we position them in the cross section of the profile?**

The net forces $F_x$ and $F_y$ calculated this way act on the origin you chose to describe the profile and the load, and their magnitude won't change as you change your choice of origin.
Conversely, the torque $T$ changes as you change the position of your (0,0) reference with respect to the profile, as stated by Varignon's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! does the distributed load/the horizontal force only take into account the normal force due to the belt or also the friction force due to the belt? I assume it takes both into account but just to be sure (they don't teach advanced vector calculations in college level courses at my school). 2 more things: if I want to also determine the vertical comp, do I just switch up the sine and cosine in the formula where you simplified the formula for the horizontal comp? How do I determine where the force is (assuming the axle of the rod is (0,0))? Sorry if I'm asking stupid quest

Comment: The distributed force takes into account the friction force too, as I started from a very general equation. If your specific case is indeed a circular section, you can use the formula with "r" and "phi" constant, but "phi" can't be zero if you want to consider friction too.  It will also be present when the axle is still, given that the belt is tensioned. 
About the force in y, I'll add it in the answer.
Those are not stupid questions at all, they're indeed important details not specified in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Net force and torque

I assume $T_1$ and $T_2$ denote tension forces in the belt. From the outside perspective, only $T_1$ and $T_2$ and their respective directions should be relevant. They will transfer force $F_r$ and torque $M_t$ to the rod.

[image: net force and moment]

- force:
  $$\overrightarrow{F}_r = \overrightarrow{T}_1+\overrightarrow{T}_2 = \left[F_{r,x}, F_{r,y}\right]$$

  - force vector components for $x$ and $y$ directions:
    $$F_{r,x} = T_1\cdot \cos\left(\theta_1+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right) + T_2\cdot \cos\left(\theta_2+\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)$$
    $$F_{r,y} = T_1\cdot \sin\left(\theta_1+\frac{3}{2}\pi\right) + T_2\cdot \sin\left(\theta_2+\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)$$
- torque:
  $$M_t = R\cdot \left(T_2-T_1\right)$$

## A more detailed analysis of tension and normal force distribution

You should end up with the same net force and torque transferred to the pulley if you sum up (integrate) these.

### Getting distributed force on pulley as a function of angle

You need 2 assumptions. The first one is radial force equilibrium at small element $d\theta$.

[image: belt element in contact with pulley: force equilibrium]

Tension forces on both sides will be basically the same and distributed normal force $Q$ will be constant and acting approximately in radial direction, so you can write:

$$2\cdot T(\theta)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{d\theta}{2}\right) = Q(\theta)\cdot R\cdot d\theta$$
from this (for small angles $\sin(d\theta)\approx d\theta$):
$$Q(\theta) = \frac{1}{R}\cdot T(\theta)$$

The second assumption is that in order for the belt to transfer torque onto the pulley, you need friction. So if you have another look at an element $d\theta$ and how the forces change due to coefficient of friction $f$, you can write the infinitesimal friction force $dT_f$ as:
$$dT_f = f\cdot Q(\theta)\cdot R\cdot d\theta$$

This force will cause the difference between $T(\theta)$ and $T(\theta+d\theta)$:
$$T(\theta)-T(\theta+d\theta) = dT_f$$

In another form:
$$-dT(\theta) = f\cdot Q(\theta)\cdot R\cdot d\theta$$
And finally:
$$Q(\theta) = -\frac{1}{f\cdot R}\cdot \frac{dT(\theta)}{d\theta}$$

#### Combining both assumptions

Combining conclusions from first and second assumptions leads to:
$$\frac{1}{R}\cdot T(\theta) = -\frac{1}{f\cdot R}\cdot \frac{dT(\theta)}{d\theta}$$
Rearanging:
$$-f\cdot d\theta = \frac{1}{T(\theta)}\cdot dT(\theta)$$

You can integrate both sides:
$$-f\cdot \int\limits_{\theta_1}^{\theta}d\theta = \int\limits_{T_1}^{T(\theta)}\frac{1}{T(\theta)}\cdot dT(\theta)$$
Resulting in:
$$f\cdot \left(\theta_1-\theta\right) = \ln\left(\frac{T(\theta)}{T_1}\right)$$

Exponentiation of both sides:
$$\exp\left(f\cdot \left(\theta_1-\theta\right)\right) = \frac{T(\theta)}{T_1}$$

From this, you will get tension force as a function of angle:
$$T(\theta) = T_1\cdot\exp\left(f\cdot \left(\theta_1-\theta\right)\right)$$

And finally, using the first assumption, you can turn tension into distributed normal force:
$$Q(\theta) = \frac{T_1}{R}\cdot\exp\left(f\cdot \left(\theta_1-\theta\right)\right)$$

Here you have some example distributions for fixed $T_1$, and angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and for different friction coefficients $f$, based on which the resulting tension force $T_2$ can be calculated:

[image: forces from belt to pulley]